# Do we have to manually set model.skip_callback to false if it was set to true somewhere?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Where I work, they set skip_callback to true manually but I couldn't find anywhere they are setting it to false. Do I have to do it, or does it becomes false automatically

```
self.skip_callback = true
self.save
```

this is how it's used in the code, it's not set to false after this

Comment: Why not ask your colleagues how this is supposed to work?

Comment: lol, they all left after giving small KT but I don't think I should discuss that here, and I believe this is rails thing not my project specific thing

Comment: Can you give a little more context then? This doesn’t seem to be a usual thing to do. Are the callbacks disabled before each `save` call or just under specific circumstances? What do you mean by "manually"?

Comment: Under specific circumstances, by manually I meant it is not the usual thing to do but it is done in many places. I have seen it's usage in migration files and scripts before but not in a controller.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay, so what does `skip_callback` do? If you want to know if it switches back to `false` automatically (e.g. after `save`), you should look at its implementation.